# Как совместить scroll и sticky

Tags: html

Мне нужно закрепить шапку у таблицы, притом чтобы у таблицы сохранился горизонтальный скролл. Помогите доработать код.

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    th {
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: -1px;
      z-index: 999;
      background-color: #000;
      color: white;
    
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2
    }
    
    .responsive {
      width: 400px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="responsive">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead th{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */

}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, только мне нужен горизонтальный скролл таблицы а не всей страницы. Я таким образом делаю адаптивность, чтобы контент на узких экранах шел в одну коронку, а таблицу можно было двигать влево-вправо пальцем, не двигая при этом всю страницу